# How to download / upload files from your nokia x6 mobile to PC using WLAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-download

Can anybody please help me to connect to my Office PC where Pan Drive or disk is not allowed

We can only use WLAN connection, I am looking for a good software that help me to upload / download files from my Nokia X6 mobile to my Windows XP PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `miniserver.exe` is best for me, it easily creates a website in you system's IIS and using that website you can easily upload/download files.

I forgot where I downloaded it from , but I found the following link in miniserver's about me.
http://www.atopo.net/

Found one more way to enable PAN drive by making changes in Registry (if your system administrator has blocked it by changing registry value). Reply me if you want to know more.

Comment: Do you have a link to that?

Comment: I forgot where I downloaded it from , but I found the following link in miniserver's about me.
http://www.atopo.net/